# Traveling to the US after being denied a visa?

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, tourist-visas

I've traveled to the US 2 times, both as a tourist, in 2015 and 2020. Had no problems at all.

In 2021, me and my wife applied to a study visa but were denied due to insufficient funds.

Will that be any problem if I ever want to go visit the US again as a tourist? If so, what can I do to solve the problem (if there's any way to)?

Comment: I suppose you mean you entered (and want to enter again) under the VWP with an ESTA? What is your citizenship?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean those two trips were made under the Visa Waiver Program (VWP) without a visa but with an ESTA, no, you will likely no longer be able to do that.

One of the eligibility questions for an ESTA reads:

> Have you ever been denied a U.S. visa you applied for with your current or previous passport, or have you ever been refused admission to the United States or withdrawn your application for admission at a U.S. port of entry?

Answering yes to that question makes it unlikely your ESTA will be approved.

If you have an ESTA which is still valid (quite unlikely if your last trip to the US was in 2020), a change to the answer to that question requires you to apply for a new one, and a likely refusal.

You will most likely need to apply for a visa for any future travel to the US.